# Use Multiple Expressions In Select List

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I am attempting to run this syntax

```
Select
[StoreName] = (Select *
              FROM OPENQUERY(192.168.5.812,'Select
                                    storename
                                    FROM stores') x
              WHERE x.storename = y.storename)
[StoreManager] = y.storemanager
FROM managerinfo y
```

But this gives me an error of

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Is it possible to do this while using `OPENQUERY`?  How can I achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your * with just the column name. Although it means the same, now it should be clear to SQL Server:

```
SELECT
    [StoreName] = (SELECT storename
                     FROM OPENQUERY(192.168.5.812, 'SELECT storename
                                    FROM stores') x
                    WHERE x.storename = y.storename)
    [StoreManager] = y.storemanager
FROM 
    managerinfo y ;
```